# Website with Browser-GUI

Tags: web-apps, gui

I am looking for a website that provides a Browser-like GUI for surfing with a GUI-less browser.

For example, back/forward navigation buttons, home button, an address bar and something like an iframe to display the selected content in. Perhaps also bookmarks.

---

For context, I am working with CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework) which lacks any sort of UI and only provides the content-display window itself, without any basic navigation GUI. Within this context, I want to provide users with a GUI.

My research lead me to solutions like:

- browser.lol
- browserling.com

However, they are way more than what I am looking for, creating a full remote session on a real browser instance in a cloud/container.

I am aware that writing such a website is probably *just* a matter of a day or two. But since this will be used for a *professional* user facing situation, I hoped to instead use an existing solution - if any exists.

Comment: Are yopu looking for a website, or for a web page template into which you will insert your own content?

Comment: A website that can be used for browsing anything existing (Google, YouTube, Facebook, ... whatever people want to visit). I figured CORS might be an issue...